# Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal T$ be the countable complement topology on $R$ and let $R$ be the set of all real numbers.

> $A$={0}, $B=Z , C=Q, D=R-Q, E=(0,1), F=[0,1]$

Which of the following subsets of $R$ is open in $(R,\mathcal T)$ ? and which of the following is a closed set ?
I don't know how to solve this problem, i want to complete my note.

Comment: Well, closed sets are exactly those which are countable. Among those you listed, which ones are countable? Which ones have countable complement?

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: Do you know what "countable" means? For example, $\Bbb{Z}$ is countable, hence it is closed.

Comment: It's unclear what part of the problem you don't understand: if you understand definition of co-countable topology ( the one you just described) and what countable sets are, this should be no problem

Comment: Can you give me reference to study about that question ? I don't understand about the general topology. I am beginer for this course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A, B, C$ are countable sets ( which means it is either finite or can be mapped one-to-one to $\mathbb{N}$),so by definition, they are closed sets.

$D$ is open set, since its complement is $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable.

$E$ and $F$ are neither open nor closed. Since they are not countable, so they are not closed sets. Their complements are not countable, so they are not open sets.

Comment: is $(R,\mathcal T)$ a Hausdorff space ?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of Hausdorff space?

Comment: the first question is determine whether open or closed set on $R$, then the new question "is $(R,\mathcal T)$ a Hausdorff space ?

Comment: It's just the definition.